# How to make subsets for an item in a list elements combining the other items from the list?

Tags: java, memory-management, collections, subset

Assume I have an `ArrayList` of strings like `[a, b, c, d, ....]`. Can anybody help me with a sample code that how can I come out with a result that contains all possible power subsets form this list which are including a particular string from that list(except the single and empty subset)?

For example: if I like to get all the power subsets including `a` from the example list then the output will be:

```
[a,b], [a,c], [a,d], [a,b,c], [a,b,d], [a,c,d] without the empty and single subset([a])
```

Similarly if I want for `b` then the output will be:

```
[b,a], [b,c], [b,d], [b,a,c], [b,a,d], [b,c,d] without the empty and single subset([b])
```

As all of the items in the example list are string then their might be a memory problem when the subsets will be too rich. Because I need to keep this subsets in memory for a single string at a time. Like when making subsets for `a` then I need those subset for some further processing and then delete them, then for `b` and so on. So I also need help about what would be the optimized solution for this scenario?

I need the help in Java. As I am not that much good at Java please pardon me if I made any mistake!

Comment: Added the `homework` tag, because I've seen a few questions very similar to this recently, you're a new user, and there is no way anyone would need to write code that did this in the real world

Answer (score 1):

If there's always only one specific element, I'd suggest something like removing the target element from the source set, using Guava's `Sets.powerSet` on the remaining set, and then adding the target element to the returned set.  Something like...

```
Set<String> elems = Sets.newHashSet(set);
elems.remove(target);
Set<Set<String>> powerSet = Sets.powerSet(elems);
Collection<Set<String>> subsetsWithTarget = Collections2.transform(
    powerSet, new Function<Set<String>, Set<String>>() {
  public Set<String> apply(Set<String> setWithoutTarget) {
    return Sets.union(setWithoutTarget, Collections.singleton(target));
  }
});
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)